# Best practice to use @Transactional annotation in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm currently working on a project using Spring boot. I haven't used `@Transactional` annotation on most of the methods. But sometimes when an error points towards having transactional annotation, then i place the annotation on it. Also i call service methods within same service class.

My Question:
Do i have to use `@Transactional` annotation on every service method.

or what is the best practice to use `@Transactional` annotation in service methods.

Comment: You don't have to mark every method as @Transactional, just the ones you want to be rolled back in case of error (e.g. you would normally mark writes, but not reads). Also note that if you call an annotated method from a non-annotated method in the same class, the annotation has no effect, because that method call won't go through the wrapping proxy class.

Comment: So, i should use annotation on those methods where i write to the database. and not on ones where i read from database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally use @Transactional on every service class (directly on the class, not the methods).  It is incredibly useful to avoid having to manage sessions / transactions yourself and i honestly don't see a reason not to have every method use it.  I have over 30 entities and associated DAO and service classes using it at the class level and everything works great.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martin. Surely will do that.

Comment: You might encounter scenarios where you need to drill down to each method for different transactional behaviors, for example if you want different transactional propagation for certain methods or different exceptions to rollback.  If you ever encounter this then you can change it to the method level with different parameters but in my honest opinion I would start with annotating the whole class first.  I am working on a very large project and that method has been fine for every service class i wrote.  Different projects will require different needs of course.

Comment: And also, if you ever need a non-transactional method in your service to call a transactional method in the same service, you will need to autowire a reference to itself into your service for the transaction to work properly.  This seems a bit odd but it has to do with the way Spring "wraps" your service class and this wrapping only works on calls happening outside the object itself.  Hope this helps!